Creating a community visualization is blocked by CORB
I'm attempting to create a community visualization in Looker Studio, but I'm encountering an issue where only a white box is displayed instead of my custom visualization. Upon investigating the problem, I discovered that my JavaScript file is being blocked by Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB). The following is what I get in the web console:
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked a cross-origin response.


 getThirdPartyScript?vizId=gs%3A%2F%2Fcommunity-viz-docs-synaxon_test%C2%A0barChart+V2&path=gs%3A%2F%2Fcommunity-viz-docs-synaxon_test%2Fcustomtable.js&cacheBuster=1733901983729

I have followed the google codelab for community visualizations.
I created a cloud storage bucket and made sure it has the correct access rights.
I made sure the JavaScript file is accessible. I also tried to configure a CORS config:
[
  {
    "origin": ["*.googleusercontent.com"],
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "POST"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]

But so far no success.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or know how to resolve this CORB blocking problem while creating a community visualization for Looker Studio? Any guidance on how to properly set up the JavaScript file or configure the visualization to comply with Looker Studio's security policies would be greatly appreciated.
Manifest
Config
